# Arduino Mega slows down after 4 hours

Tags: json, arduino, char, httpresponse, memory-fragmentation

I'm making a small project that makes some POST request to an webserver and do some tasks based on server response. Server always respond with JSON or an array

Clasic response from server looks like :

```
POST /app_dev.php/api/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=vagrant HTTP/1.1 
Host: XXXXXX.vagrant:8080 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Postman-Token: 37fddefd-e120

id=594cdf2c962d740c2b1dac22&identifier=594cdf2c962d740c2b1dac22
```

The problem is that after 4 hours of running flawless my arduino mega is running very very slow. First time, it takes only 10-20ms to retrive a command and execute task (power on a led). Now, after 4 hours, it takes around 5 seconds to power the same led. I saw that ethernet leds are blinking slowly. I guess is because I've used some const char* to store server response. 
My question is, at the end of the loop function, variables like const char* are deleted ?
What does my arduino to run so slowly after few hours ? Thanks

Code that runs in loop function :

```
    void loop () {

  dataReceived = 0;
  apiResponseReceived = 1; 
  apiCommandsResponseReceived = 1;
  sendConfirmationCommand = 0;
  checkForConfirmationResponse = 0;;
  payloadData dataPacket,dataBuffer;
  tmElements_t tm;

  RTC.read(tm);


  Serial.print("some things ");
  Serial.println(queueEncrypted.count());
  Serial.print("some things");
  Serial.println(queueDecrypted.count());
  printf_P(PSTR("Free ram: %d"),freeRam());



  if(apiCommandsResponseReceived == 1) {
    Serial.print("flag message");
    byte check = stash.create();
    stash.print("identifier=");
    stash.print("8234nsda987123");
    stash.save();
    int stash_size = stash.size();
    Stash::prepare(PSTR("POST http://$F/$F HTTP/1.0" "\r\n"
      "Host: $F" "\r\n"
      "Connection: close" "\r\n"
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "\r\n"
      "Content-Length: $D" "\r\n"
      "\r\n"
      "$H"),
    website,readCommands,website, stash_size, check);
    // send the packet - this also releases all stash buffers once done

    sessionDoi = ether.tcpSend();

    int freeCount = stash.freeCount();

    if (freeCount <= 3) {
       Stash::initMap(56);
     }

    apiCommandsResponseReceived = 0;
  }


  long timeCommand = millis();

  while(millis()- timeCommand < 5000) {

    word len = ether.packetReceive(); // go receive new packets
    word pos = ether.packetLoop(len); // respond to incoming pings
    const char* reply2 = ether.tcpReply(sessionDoi);
    StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
    Serial.print("flag message");

    if (reply2 != 0) {
      Serial.println(F(" >>>REPLY recieved...."));
      Serial.println(reply2);
      reply2 = removeHTTPHeader(reply2);
      Serial.println("------HEADER REMOVED-----");
      Serial.println(reply2);
      JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(reply2);
      if (root.success()) {
        const char* id = root["id"];
        strcpy(global_ID_command,id);
        const char* command = root["command"];
        const char* value = root["value"];
        Serial.print("id: ");
        Serial.println(id);
        Serial.print("id glabal: ");
        Serial.println(global_ID_command);
        Serial.print("comanda: ");
        Serial.println(command);
        Serial.print("flag message");
        Serial.print(value);
        int comanda = atoi(value);

        if(comanda == 1){
          Serial.print("e 1");
          digitalWrite(error_ETH,HIGH);
        }

        if(comanda == 0 ){
          Serial.print("e 0");
          digitalWrite(error_ETH,LOW);
        }
        sendConfirmationCommand = 1;
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("flag message");
      }


      if (strstr(reply2,success)) {
        Serial.println("flag message");
      }
      apiCommandsResponseReceived = 1;
      jsonBuffer.clear();
      break;
    }
  }

  pingSite(ether.hisip, 1, 500);

  if(sendConfirmationCommand == 1) {
    Serial.print("flag message");
    byte response = stash.create();
    stash.print("response%5Bcommand%5D=");
    stash.print(global_ID_command);
    stash.print("&response%5Bcurrent_state%5D=");
    stash.print("ON");
    stash.print("&response%5Bsuccess%5D=");
    stash.print("true");
    stash.save();
    int stash_size = stash.size();
    Stash::prepare(PSTR("POST http://$F/$F HTTP/1.0" "\r\n"
      "Host: $F" "\r\n"
      "Connection: close" "\r\n"
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "\r\n"
      "Content-Length: $D" "\r\n"
      "\r\n"
      "$H"),
    website,executeCommands,website, stash_size, response);
    // send the packet - this also releases all stash buffers once done

    sessionTrei = ether.tcpSend();

    int freeCount = stash.freeCount();

    if (freeCount <= 3) {
       Stash::initMap(56);
     }

    sendConfirmationCommand = 0;
    checkForConfirmationResponse = 1;
  }


 if(checkForConfirmationResponse == 1){

   long timeExecute = millis();

   while(millis()- timeExecute < 5000) {

     word len = ether.packetReceive(); // go receive new packets
     word pos = ether.packetLoop(len); // respond to incoming pings
     const char* reply3 = ether.tcpReply(sessionTrei);

     Serial.print("flag message");

     if (reply3 != 0) {
       Serial.println(F(" >>>REPLY recieved...."));
       Serial.println(reply3);
       reply3 = removeHTTPHeader(reply3);
       Serial.println("------HEADER REMOVED-----");
       Serial.println(reply3);
       if (strstr(reply3,success)) {
         Serial.println("flag message");
       }
       checkForConfirmationResponse = 0;
       break;
     }
   }
 }
```

Function to remove headers from tcp response

```
    char *removeHTTPHeader(char *buffer) {
    char *t = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");
    t = t + 4;
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This smells like the classic dynamic memory thrashing problem.  You don't say what ethernet library(ies) you are using, so I won't venture to guess whether they are using `malloc` et al.

I can say that the JSON library does not use dynamic memory, so I doubt the slow-down has anything to do with parsing the response.

Without the complete code set, I would suggest freeing up as much RAM as you can, to alleviate the "search" for memory by `malloc`.  The single biggest culprit is your use of double-quoted string constants.  Wrap all string literals you `print` with the `F` macro:

```
Serial.print( F("comanda: ") );
```

You did that for some, but not all.  Also, the JSON library *appears* to support using FLASH strings, so change all your references to:

```
const char* command = root[ F("command") ];
```

This does not save any memory in the JSON object itself, but it does save the RAM for that identifier.

#### This may do nothing but extend the time you can run.

After that, you may want to look at what functions in the ethernet/Stash code do, to determine if you can limit your use of calls that fragment the heap.  If there's nothing obvious, you may want to use the Watch Dog Timer to force a reset after some predetermined time.

Yay dynamic memory in embedded systems.  -_-